# Show major tick on google meter gauge chart with amount as $1k , $2.5 M

Tags: javascript, api, community, jquery, charts

I am creating visualforce page which contains a google meter gauge chart as shown above. I am showing trying to show amount in gauge but as you know representation of amount in 1K , 1M ,1B will give it more specific information rather then displaying about 10 digit number. Has any body inserted a google chart in visual force page with an amount. If yes pls give an guidance so that it will be an easy solution for me.[image]